# Windows Forms Data Grid Row Display Problem

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using windows forms and while I was doing something, I noticed that my datagridview isnt working correctly.

Here is my code:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            table.Columns.Add("aa", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("AA", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Aa", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("aA", typeof(string));

            string[] arr = { "BB", "Bb", "bB", "bb"};

            table.Rows.Add(arr);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

I expect that I see a table with these columns `aa ; AA ; Aa ; aA` and the row `BB ; Bb ; bB ; bb`.

The columns are displayed correctly, but the row is displayed as:

```
BB ; BB ; BB ; BB
```

Why is this happening?

Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason it is not working above is because you are adding an entire row to arr[0]. To fix this you have to assign each value in row to the appropriate column. Try doing the following to get the results you want:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] arr = { "BB", "Bb", "bB", "bb" };
        int numberOfColumns = 4;
        int numberOfRows = 4;

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("aa", "aa");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("AA", "AA");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Aa", "Aa");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("aA", "aA");

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(numberOfRows);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1[i, 0].Value = arr[i];
        }
    }
```

If you want to use the datasource I would create a class first, add my values to each property (column) of the class like below:

```
class MyValues
{
    public string aa { get; set; }
    public string AA { get; set; }
    public string Aa { get; set; }
    public string aA { get; set; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<MyValues> list = new List<MyValues>();

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list.Add(new MyValues { aa = "BB", AA = "Bb", Aa = "bB", aA = "bb" });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, your answer isnt completly correct, but with it I could find the problem: I have to use dataGridView1.Rows.Add(arr); instead of table.Rows.Add(arr);   Anyway, thanks for helping +rep

Comment: @LPeSi: No, you don't have to do that, which effectively means giving up on DataBinding. The recommended solution is instead to use proper column names!

Answer (score 1):

Your columns all have the same name.

C# is case-sensitive but the `DataTable` can't tell them apart as they are.

Give them different names and all is well:

```
table.Columns.Add("aa1", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("AA2", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Aa3", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("aA4", typeof(string));
```

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.columnname?view=netframework-4.8#siehe-auch) on column names:

> The name comparison is not case sensitive.

This is a strange finding as one would expect a [DuplicateNameException](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.duplicatenameexception?view=netframework-4.8):

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumncollection.add?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataColumnCollection_Add_System_String_System_Type_) on `DataColumnCollection.Add`:

> The collection already has a column with the specified name. (The
>   comparison is not case-sensitive.)

..but it isn't raised.